# Android installing app in device with differnt package name

Tags: android, package-name

i have an android app and i have same app with another package name but i can't install both at same device.even different package name.while tried to install it shows a conflict message like can't install app with same version. how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the "same", but with a **different** package name, then you are probably have a conflict with content provider URIs, those must be unique too. Change those to reflect your modified package name.

Comment: How can i change content provider uri..?

Comment: It is listed in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Look for: <provider android:authorities="com.example.provider".

Comment: Thanks i change it..it's problem was fb content provider

Comment: Great. Did it install properly?

Answer (score 0):

You may  have same providers in both packages. For example file providers